# Remove index.php from url on apache 2.4.6 on zend framework

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, zend-framework, apache2.4

I have a project in zend framework 1 where, google indexed links with http://www.example.com/index.php/url in them instead of http://www.example.com/url, thus creating duplicates and unwanted links.

I have this rule in htaccess

```
 RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

that worked fine until we upgraded Apache to 2.4.6, since then it only redirected links like www.example.com/index.phpurl and not www.example.com/index.php/url, index.php/url does not appear to be included in this expression.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Comment: As I found there is a bug in Apache 2.4.6 https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53929. I cannot for now change the apache version, so I need a solution to deploy in .htaccess to solve this.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /myproject/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: The OP wants to redirect the old links.

Comment: this does not help me redirect the links in any way. As i stated, the rule worked before upgrading Apache to 2.4.6, but doesn't after that.